# How do I help my staff be happy?

Tags: planet-coaster

I feel like I have a number of things figured out, but my staff keeps quitting their jobs. I've added some staff areas, but it doesn't seem to help. How do I make sure my staff are happy in the park?

Comment: Do the low-happiness staffmembers have any complaints in their thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to why personnel quits, it's either because they're:

1. overworked and underpaid or
2. underworked and overtrained regardless of reasonable salary